# Removing values from object of arrays modifies the entire object even when iterated over keys

Tags: javascript

**Performing operations on object of arrays:**

-----code -------

```
 var obj1 = { 'a': ['a','b','c','d'], 'b':['b','d','r','a']}
    Object.keys(obj1).forEach(element => {
        var range = obj1[element].indexOf(element);
        if (range !== -1) {
            obj1[element].splice(range, 1);
        }});
    
    Result: {
        "a": [  "c",  "d" ],
        "b": [ "d","r"]
    }
```

Comment: what is your issue again and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The issue is that , there is an object of arrays, where the key of the object can be in the values array of the key. e.g. var obj1 = { 'a': ['a','b','c','d']}. Here 'a' is present in value array of key 'a'. So I need to remove the value from the array when the key is a part of the values array. So I want the result to be var obj1 = {'a': ['b','c','d]} Unfortunately the entire object is updated removing all keys from all values. Check the result I have given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search for the index and remove the unwanted key.

```js
var object = {
  a: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  b: ['b', 'd', 'r', 'a']
};

Object.keys(object).forEach((key, _, keys) => {
    var index;
    while ((index = object[key].indexOf(key)) !== -1)
        object[key].splice(index, 1);
});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Nina Scholz: I want the result to be {
        "a": [ "b", "c",  "d" ],
        "b": [ "d","r", "a" ]
    }. But I am getting the result I have given in the intial question. So it is updating the entire object inspite of foreach applied on keys